# Do cloudy beers produce worse hangovers?

Tags: hangover

I drank some 11 small bottles of Moretti the other night, with no hangover.

I've noticed though, that if I drink a similar amount of say a Weissbeer, I feel it the next day.

Thus my question: **Do cloudy ales produce worse hangovers? And does quality play a part?**

Comment: I don’t know, but Moretti is only 4.6% abv whereas Weissbier is more like 5.4% abv. That’s about 17% more alcohol.

Comment: Perhaps, it could be a difference regarding the amount and type of grain, where the Weissbier triggers some grain sensitivity?

Comment: @morsor That is an interesting thought. Weissbiers have a lot of wheat, I believe, which might be an issue for someone who is gluten sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

**Do cloudy beers produce worse hangovers?**

I would like to say **no**.

Having drank many cloudy beers and wines back in the day, they make no difference to me.

Generally speaking, the more alcohol you drink, the more likely you are to have a hangover the next day.

> A hangover is a group of unpleasant signs and symptoms that can develop after drinking too much alcohol. As if feeling awful weren't bad enough, frequent hangovers are also associated with poor performance and conflict at work.
>
> As a general rule, the more alcohol you drink, the more likely you are to have a hangover the next day. But there's no magic formula to tell you how much you can safely drink and still avoid a hangover.
>
> However unpleasant, most hangovers go away on their own, though they can last up to 24 hours. If you choose to drink alcohol, doing so responsibly can help you avoid future hangovers. - [Hangovers](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hangovers/symptoms-causes/syc-20373012)

Comment: Of course and how does that relate to cloudy beers, as opposed to any other form of alcohol?